# How to add fragment activity to MainActivity.java or MainAcyivity.kt

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, fingerprint, localauthentication

I am trying to build fingerprint fitur in my flutter apps and I am using [local_auth package](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth)... the problem is that I always get below error-

```
PlatformException(no_fragment_activity, local_auth plugin requires activity to be a FragmentActivity., null)
```

I try to add FragmentActivity to MainActivity.kt but it doesn't work.. here is the structure of my folder... so should I create MainActivity.java? and where should I place MainActivity.java in my folder?

[image]

and here is the content of my MainActivity.kt

```
package com.project

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

Comment: no, mainActivity.java is not needed as by default the .kt version has been created. Try not to edit the MainActivity.kt for now , I recommend you https://pub.dev/packages/biometric instead

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with Kotlin

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

import android.os.Build
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver


class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {
  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }
}
```